# GSA metadata limit?

Tags: google-search-appliance

We have a page with a metadata field which is also configured in GSA's dynamic configuration. The meta value is comma-separated and can get quite lengthy.

It is observed that whenever the meta value length crosses 90 characters, GSA does not recognize it as a facet i.e. no `<PMT>` nodes are returned for it in the GSA search response. Is this a known restriction?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, There is a limitation associated with metadata in Google search appliance.Below url talks about the limitation. http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/70/gsa_doc_set/xml_reference/request_format.html#1078040

https://support.google.com/gsa/answer/4411411#meta

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time when you have comma-separate metadata values, you want to treat them as multiple individual values rather than one single value. You can control this under Index Settings.

Comment: Yes, we had this configured initially, but it was found that there could be commas within a value as well. We couldn't ever arrive at a "safe" character set which could be used as separator.